# Absolute path of an EAR File

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports, ear

I am using *Java*, *JBoss 5.1*, *EJB* and *JasperReports* library to generate reports.

We have a jrxml  with a subreport  and subreport expression is *`$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ACC0401-RebatePayableAgingClosedLoans - SR1.jasper"`*

Where *`$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}`*  is being passed from *Java* and file name ie *"ACC0401-RebatePayableAgingClosedLoans - SR1.jasper"* is known only to report.

Java is not aware about file name *`"ACC0401-RebatePayableAgingClosedLoans - SR1.jasper"`*, so I cant use *`getResourceAsStream()`*.

Now, I want to pass from *Java* code the following absolute path which is basically inside the EAR file.

```
/usr/local/jboss5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/OceanviewEAR.ear/OceanviewEJB.jar/com/oceanview/jasper/resource/config
```

My question is: In *Java*,  how can I get the absolute path of EAR File so that i can pass that absolute path to *JR* report and then report will be able to locate the actual *.jasper* file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: use a URL instead of an absolute path.

```
InputStream url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Report.jasper");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(url, params, ds);
```